# Will my UPS interface be recognized --> How to know if my current kernel version will support the class USB CDC-ACM kernel 2.6?

Tags: drivers, kernel, compatibility, ups

I'm running on:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-135-generic x86_64)
```

I'm seeking out an uninterruptible power supply (known as a *no-break* where I live) which can shut down linux in the event of energy loss. I've already found some info on https://networkupstools.org/ddl/#_supported_devices.

A manufacturer (NHS.COM.BR) specifies in order for the UPS' USB interface to be recognized, Ubuntu's kernel should support USB CDC-ACM class (NHS says kernel 2.6 or 2.4 "patched"). UPS manual can be accessed on (portuguese):
https://www.nhs.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Manual-NHSUPS-SW-3.0.30.pdf.

I have been reading some info on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_version_history; but it seems latin to me.

Prior to purchasing the UPS I should really know if this functionality will be supported by my OS.

- Is there backward compatibilty of kernel engines for USB interfaces?
- Or should I just compile this *umodem* into Ubuntu (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man4/umodem.4freebsd.html#history)?

Thanks in advance (I am really new to all of this...)

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to check that the device you plan to buy "will be supported by my OS". (Is "my OS"=Ubuntu, or is there another OS?)

Usually, when it says 2.6 or later, it should work with later kernels, including 5.4.0-135-generic.

There is a builtin module `cdc-acm.ko` available:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/ -iname "*cdc-acm*"
/lib/modules/5.4.0-135-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.ko
```

No umodem or ucom though.